# Area between curve and the line x = 4

Tags: calculus

I'm slightly confused about the following question:

Find the area between $y^2 = x$ and the line $x = 4$. So I've done other area questions but they have been presented a bit differently to this.

My first instinct is to find $y$. i.e. $y = \sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, and my limits of integration then are a = 0 and b = 4. So altogether I want 
$\int_{0}^{4} x^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$. Is that all there is to it?

Because if I sketch $y^2 = x$, it is not the same graph as $y = \sqrt{x}$
 (I understand that we are in the real 2-dimensional plane, not imaginary), but this is throwing me a bit wondering if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Moony.Draw y^2 =x. y=0,x=0.y=+-1, x=1, y=+-2, x=4. When you write y=+√ x, do you get everything?

Comment: We have to consider $y = \sqrt{x} = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $y = -\sqrt{x} $. For symmetry we can compute twice the integral you have indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that we can write

$$\int dA=2\int_0^4 \sqrt x\, dx$$

or as an alternative

$$\int dA=16-\int_{-2}^2 y^2 dy$$

Comment: Thanks. I understand the first integral and where you got it from but I do not know where you got the 'alternative' one from. Specifically the 16 - part. I undertstand where you got the limits of 2 and -2 and that you are integrating $y^2$, but why subtract the whole lot from 16 (which comes from $x^2$ I'm guessing??). This is not something I have dealt with before.

Comment: Note that the integral part is the area under the parabola up to the y axis but we need the complement that is the square $4\times4=16$ minus the integral.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not 100% getting it. I'm looking at the graph and am almost there but still not fully there. So what you are saying is that when we have $\int_{-2}^{2} y^2 dy$ , this is not solely finding the area that we want? It is finding the area of the square that is there?

Comment: No the integral represents the area between the y axis and the parabola but we need the area between x=4 and the parabola.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to get it. I just don't see how that if we are taking our limits as $-2$ and $2$ how $\int_{-2}^{2}y^2 dy$ represents the area between the $y$-axis and the parabola and not taking the $x =4$ into account.

Comment: Simply consider the axes reversed, I can’t make a sketch now, maybe later. It’s a simple fact.

Comment: Ok thanks. If you don't mind I'll leave the question open just in case you do get time for a sketch, but I'll close it later and accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. What you said is just the same as $\int_{-2}^{2} 4 -y^2 dy$ isn't it? I've been so silly I see it now thank you.

Comment: Yes of course! That’s all!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye